# Keep page enumeration between portrait and landscape pages

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, page-numbering

I am using Word 2013 and in my document I use both portrait and landscapes pages. The problem is that when I add the page enumeration, it gets restarted when the page orientation changes because it is considered as a different section.

How to keep the same correlation of page/number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select ***Insert*** from the top bar. Then in the column *"Headers and Footers"*, click on ***Page Number*** then select ***"Format Page Numbers"*** as shown below:

[image: image1]

Now select ***"Continue from previous section"*** under *Page Numbering* as shown below:

[image: pagenumberformat]

Comment: Thank you so much!